# How do I export and show my timetable from codepen

Tags: javascript, html, css, timeline, codepen

Ok, to start with i made a timeline on codepen. 
Heres the working link:
https://codepen.io/morganjaggers/pen/VwYmKra

Please check out the link above for full code

html:

```
<section class="timeline">
<ul>
<li>
<div>
<time>1989</time> We began our family run business creating small travel packages for 
independent travellers to visit areas within the UK.
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div>
<time>1997</time> We expanded out, connecting to other supliers to created packages outside 
of Europe.
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div>
<time>2003</time>We won awards and became more established as a company.
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div>
<time>2010</time>We started searching for cheaper deals, focusing on those looking for a 
budget holiday.
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div>
<time>2017</time>We become what we are now known today as TravelTipsForLess.
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</section>
```

However, when i code and paste EXACTLY each file into my ATOM document, it doesn't work. It shows the Timeline and the dots but the JS isnt working and the HTML writing isnt appearing?

Anyone know why it is working in Codepen but not when I export it out?

Comment: I am putting them all into external files and refrencing the CSS and JS in the head tag in HTML correctly. It has worked for other projects however this one is forgetting the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Codepen doesn't require you to use `<script>` or `<style>` tags in its sandbox environment.

You need to put javascript inside `<script></script>` and CSS inside `<style></style>`, using this format below.

Save the file as an HTML document, and then you can view it in your browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <style>
        // CSS HERE
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    // HTML HERE

    <script>
        // JAVASCRIPT HERE
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, so I have done the format correctly. It has worked with other files however this one will not.

Comment: Hi, I've just tried copying each of the css, html, and js snippets from your Codepen into the template above and it loads perfectly fine for me. So if your css and js are external it must be an issue with your file references